# C# FTP upload file priority for multiple files inside a folder

Tags: c#, ftp

I have an FTP function which syncs local folders to a remote FTP directory where it is then processed by a server-side script to create password protected photo galleries. Typically there are 4 to 6 jpg files and a single txt file. The txt file is simply a text string which is parsed to create a password for the gallery. It works fine, unless the folder being synchronized is over 6MB or so. Then it's hit and miss because the password file is sometimes not uploaded until after the photos. When this happens, the server interprets as "no password file, so create gallery without password." This seems to be a logical flaw in how files are processed on the server script, but I am using a commercially licensed gallery so I may have to address on my end.

My dilemma is figuring out how to prioritize the files uploaded inside the folder so that the txt file is always first, followed by jpg files. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without sample code showing what you've tried, this will get closed out. However I can suggest that it should be something as simple as listing the contents of the folder to be uploaded, picking anything ending in .txt first and then going forward as normal.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the following on how to ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Theoretically, the order in which you upload (start uploading) files will be your priority. But practically we are talking about an IP network I suppose - thus you can start uploading the txt as first, and still finish as last, even if it is far smaller than the other files. The only approach I can imagine is to start uploading the txt, wait until it is finished, an then start uploading the photos in parallel. Although that might be also problematic on the server side. But let me state, that this is a quite bad design after all.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a list of files, e.g. by using `Directory.GetFiles()`,  and do not upload them in parallel you just need to [order them](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.7.2) according to [their extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getextension?view=netframework-4.7.2).

```
foreach(var file in fileList.OrderBy(c => Path.GetExtension(c) == ".txt" ? 0 : 1) {
 // Upload the file
}
```

If you want to upload in parallel you would need to first select your txt-file (e.g. using a where-Clause instead of an OrderBy-clause) and upload it and afterwards continue with the normal upload process for all other files.